Isa 54 is about God's reconciliation with Israel. But Isaiah 54:9 states "So I have sworn that I will Not be angry with you .." is over-the-top
Isaiah 54 for the most part describes God’s reconciliatory relationship with the Israelites.
Isaiah 54:1, 4-9, 15, 17 NASB95

1 “Shout for joy, O barren one, you who have borne no child; Break forth into joyful shouting and cry aloud, you who have not travailed; For the sons of the desolate one will be more numerous Than the sons of the married woman,” says the Lord.
4 ... And the reproach of your widowhood you will remember no more. 5 “For your husband is your Maker, Whose name is the Lord of hosts; And your Redeemer is the Holy One of Israel, Who is called the God of all the earth. 6 “For the Lord has called you, Like a wife forsaken and grieved in spirit, Even like a wife of one’s youth when she is rejected,” Says your God.
7 “For a brief moment I forsook you, But with great compassion I will gather you. 8 “In an outburst of anger I hid My face from you for a moment, But with everlasting loving kindness I will have compassion on you,” Says the Lord your Redeemer.
9 “For this is like the days of Noah to Me, When I swore that the waters of Noah Would not flood the earth again; So I have sworn that I will not be angry with you Nor will I rebuke you.
...
15 “If anyone fiercely assails you it will not be from Me. Whoever assails you will fall because of you. ... 17 “No weapon that is formed against you will prosper; And every tongue that accuses you in judgment you will condemn. This is the heritage of the servants of the Lord, And their vindication is from Me,” declares the Lord.

Isaiah 54:9 NASB95

(a) “For this is like the days of Noah to Me, When I swore that the waters of Noah (b) Would not flood the earth again; (c) So I have sworn that I will not be angry with you Nor will I rebuke you.

The very last part of Isaiah 54:9 (c) seems a bit oversimplified, and facile.
The reason being is that Isaiah 54:9 (c) states that God will not be angry at Israel and never rebuke the Israelite nation which seems extreme.
However, one of the major thematic narratives of the Bible is the cyclic nature of God’s relationship with The Bridal Israelite nation which involves

God and Israel have a romantic-live loving relationship when Israel obediently follows & yearns for God

God’s disciplinary “tough” Love that can involve “Righteous” Anger towards Israel manifesting whenever Israel rebels against God


It would have made more sense if Isaiah 54:9 (c) stated that God would Only show His Anger towards Israel and Rebuke Israel for a short season in time.
Doesn’t Isaiah 54:9 (c) seem oddly out of place?  Or is Isaiah 54:9 (c) just resorting to the literary device of hyperbole?  Could someone please conduct an exegesis of Isaiah 54:9 (c) within the larger context of Isaiah 59?

In Isaiah 54 the author describes a future time when God will restore his people and they will not fall away again - ever.
Looking at the context:

1 “Sing, O barren one, who did not bear;
break forth into singing and cry aloud,
you who have not been in labor!
For the children of the desolate one will be more
than the children of her who is married,” says the Lord.
2 “Enlarge the place of your tent,
and let the curtains of your habitations be stretched out;
do not hold back; lengthen your cords
and strengthen your stakes.
3 For you will spread abroad to the right and to the left,
and your offspring will possess the nations
and will people the desolate cities.
4 “Fear not, for you will not be ashamed;
be not confounded, for you will not be disgraced;
for you will forget the shame of your youth,
and the reproach of your widowhood you will remember no more.
5 For your Maker is your husband,
the Lord of hosts is his name;
and the Holy One of Israel is your Redeemer,
the God of the whole earth he is called.
6 For the Lord has called you
like a wife deserted and grieved in spirit,
like a wife of youth when she is cast off,
says your God.
7 For a brief moment I deserted you,
but with great compassion I will gather you.
8 In overflowing anger for a moment
I hid my face from you,
but with everlasting love I will have compassion on you,”
says the Lord, your Redeemer.
9 “This is like the days of Noah to me:
as I swore that the waters of Noah
should no more go over the earth,
so I have sworn that I will not be angry with you,
and will not rebuke you.

Notice the word "will" indicating a future time.
Verse:
1 - For the children of the desolate one will be more
than the children of her who is married"
3 - For you will spread abroad to the right and to the left,
and your offspring will possess the nations
and will people the desolate cities.
4 - Fear not, for you will not be ashamed;
be not confounded, for you will not be disgraced;
for you will forget the shame of your youth,
and the reproach of your widowhood you will remember no more.
7 - For a brief moment I deserted you,
but with great compassion I will gather you.
8 - but with everlasting love I will have compassion on you,”
says the Lord, your Redeemer.
Which brings us to verse 9.
The flood during Noah's time was a disaster that is compared here to the disaster of the exile in Babylon. Just as God promised to never flood the world again, in this future time described by Isaiah God is promising that his people will not go through another Babylon type disaster. God will not be angry with his people or rebuke them again as he did in the time of the Babylon disaster.
Given the context verse 9 is not hyperbolic.
The message given by God to Isaiah in verse 10 follows:
10 For the mountains may depart
and the hills be removed,
but my steadfast love shall not depart from you,
and my covenant of peace shall not be removed,”
says the Lord, who has compassion on you.
Isaiah is describing a time when God will break the sin cycle forever.

"Is Isaiah 54:9 just resorting to the literary device of hyperbole?"
No. This was a moment of hope and reconciliation. It describes God's feeling for the nation of Israel after they had repented and paid the price of national destruction and exile. The passage represents the culmination of the Servant Songs beginning with chapter 40:

1 Comfort, give comfort to my people,
says your God. 2 Speak to the heart of Jerusalem, and proclaim to her
that her service has ended,
that her guilt is expiated, That she has received from the hand of the Lord
double for all her sins.

Rather than hyperbole, Isaiah 54 expresses God's actual feeling in the moment of Israel's liberation. They have suffered enough, God's anger has abated, and Israel can now be reconciled with God as her husband. A parallel is found in the prophecy of Hosea 2:

18 On that day—oracle of the Lord— You shall call me “My husband,”
and you shall never again call me “My baal.” 19 I will remove from her mouth the names of the Baals;
they shall no longer be mentioned by their name.

These prophets portray God is almost human in His love for Israel, his bride. As the eternal Bridegroom, God sees only Israel virginal purity and does not remember her sin. Indeed this can be seen as a consistent theme in Isaiah from beginning to end: "Though your sins be as scarlet, they shall be white as snow" (Isaiah 1:18) and "the former things shall not be remembered nor come to mind." (Isaiah 65:17) Certainly there are other passages where God does remember Israel's sins; but here, the prophet shows us God's romantic aspect.
